# Why are some parts not rendered on a bigger window?

Tags: linux, opengl, glu

If I change the window size the objects are deformed(as I know).
So Im trying to calculate the aspect but If I do this and I increase the window size only a smal rectangle is rendered.

This are the relevant parts of the code :

Reshape function :

```
void ReshapeFunc(int x, int y)
{
  aspect = (float) x/y;
}
```

(apect is defined global)

gluPerspective :

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(90, aspect, near, far);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `glViewport(0, 0, width, height)` anytime you change the size of the window.